# Shrinking Bootstrap Navbar with logo on scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I need the fixed navbar to shrink 50% when it starts scrolling.

I have seen just text navbars, but nothing with a logo.  Any help would be much appreciated.

http://carpetliquidators.com/demo/

You can pull the css and html from there.

Comment: If you want some help you should add some code of your page and what you have tried

Comment: I believe you'll need javascript.  Check out window.onscroll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished by using jQuery and a custom CSS class, like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
    }
    else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
```

Comment: The link does not work anymore. Can you please update it?

Comment: Looks like the links are dead, so I've removed them.