# shrinking navigation bar with Bootstrap 2.3.2 in Joomla 3.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, navbar, joomla3.4

I'm trying to get a 'shrinking' navbar in Joomla 3.4 (which uses Bootstrap 2.3.2). I tried to implement the solution from [Shrinking Bootstrap Navbar with logo on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050763/shrinking-bootstrap-navbar-with-logo-on-scroll) But it is based on Bootstrap 3 and so it doesn't seem to work properly.

This is the site/page I'm building: http://www.shespeakswithpassionmembership.com/

This is the navbar that I have implemented in the Joomla template:

```
        <!-- navigation bar -->
    <div id="navwikkel" class="row-fluid">
        <nav class="span12 navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top normal" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar navbbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/thomsterdamparallax/images/logo.png" /></a>
                    <p class="menuklikhier visible-phone visible-tablet hidden-desktop">menu
                    </p>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="navigatie" style="none" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
      <!-- end navigation bar -->
```

You may need to have a look in the css file to get a glimpse of what I'm using there.